# MVC 5 with @Scripts.Render(“~/bundles/jquery”) Compilation Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm developing an MVC5 project that have Payfast implementation. I have a View that submit all the information to the Payfast website for payment. If i run the project it always give me `Compilation Error`pointing to `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`. I'm confused please help.

This is the view that is giving me the problem.

```
 @model Template.Model.PayFastModel

<body>
    <form id="hiddenform" action=@Model.actionURL>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.merchant_id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.merchant_key)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.m_payment_id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.payment_mode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.name_first)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.name_last)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.email_address)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.site)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cancel_return)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.notify_url)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)
    </form>

    <br/><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <p style="text-align: center">
        <h3>
            Connecting to Payfast , please wait ...

        </h3>
    </p>
</body>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(this.document).ready(function () {
        var form = $("form");
        form.submit();
    });
</script>
```

The error message:[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please show us the full, exact error message.

Comment: What does your bundle setup look like in your `BundleConfig.cs`?

Comment: I don't have a `BundleConfig.cs` in my project. Do I have to have one? If i should include it how must it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the following line in the `web.config` in the `Views` folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ...
      <!-- THIS LINE: -->
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

Additionally, you may also be missing the reference to the `System.Web.Optimization` assembly, ensure that it exists.

Comment: Adding `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />` in the `web.config` in the  solved `Views` helped me. Thanks a lot for help.